# Grid based A* pathfinding and surrounding in Unity C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8flV.png)I am trying to create adequate 2D A* pathfinding based on grids on an isometric plane for my kingdom builder in Unity C#. Currently, every grid has a Row and Col to identify its position in world space and in grid space. When my objects find their target, they find the closest not taken grid (isTaken == false) and move to it, taking it (isTaken = true) in the process. This is done via a for loop that runs exactly once every time an object is spawned. Currently the code is setup so that if enough objects are spawned, they will surround the two closest sides of the target, but if more objects are spawned than available grids it leads to very low fps and eventually a crash. I cannot remove the breaks, it leads to an almost instant crash.

Every variable used:
GameObject[] aiTargets - is the array where every grid is stored
int iIndex, iRow, iCol - are the values used to identify the row and column of every grid in the for loo. Column and index are usedin the field, where a 4x4 grid space has indexes from 0 to 15
int startRow, startCol - getting real time row and column of the moving object
int selectedTarget - counter for amount of spawned objects used to surround a target
int endIndex, endRow, endCol - values used to find the row and column of the final grid of the path
_attributes.range - the range of the object in grid spaces. if object range is 3, it stops 3 grids from its target (be it rows, columns or both when in perfect 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees)

Image for Reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLhxJ.jpg
Currently, once the target grids are all taken, a crash occurs.
In the example in the picture, the intended outcome is for the 18 units to spread equally to all 9 available spaces. Once #1 is taken, they move to #2 and so on. Once #9 is taken they are expected to go back to #1 and repeat.

This is the for loop used to find the closest not taken grid

```
for (int i = 0; i < aiTargets.Length; i++)
{
    iIndex = GridManager.instance.GetGridIndex(aiTargets[i].transform.position); // Gridmanager.Instance.GetGridIndex tarnsforms position to index on the grid
    iRow = GridManager.instance.GetRow(iIndex); // GetRow and GetColumn use the index to identify the row and column
    iCol = GridManager.instance.GetColumn(iIndex);

    // Big if/else to find from which direction the object is moving towards the target
    if (startRow < iRow) // check when objectRow < targetRow
    {
        if (startCol < iCol) // further check if the objectCol < targetCol 
        {
            if (!GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range].isTaken) // GridManager.instance.nodes[,] returns a grid (i.e. [4, 5] and checks if isTaken)
            {
                endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range].position; // if it is not taken, the endpos takes the value and returns it to the object as the final point
                GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range].isTaken = true; // sets the selected grid to isTaken = true
                break; // Breaks the for so it doesnt lag
            }

            else // iF the grid is taken, finds the closest grid that is in range based on the unit
            {
                if (selectedTarget % 2 == 0) // selectedTarget is checked if odd or even to distribute objects accordingly to each side - (example: objects come from below, one goes to the left, one to the right)
                {
                    // the calculations below are used to return a grid that is in range and by using selectedtarget/2 it is made sure that no grid is skipped
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range + selectedTarget / 2, iCol - _attributes.range].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range + selectedTarget / 2, iCol - _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range + (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range + (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else //From around True east
        {
            if (!GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range].isTaken)
            {
                endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range].position;
                GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (selectedTarget % 2 == 0)
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range + selectedTarget / 2, iCol + _attributes.range].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range + selectedTarget / 2, iCol + _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range - (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow - _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range - (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (startCol < iCol)
        {
            if (!GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range].isTaken)
            {
                endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range].position;
                GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                break;
            }
            else // From around True West
            {
                if (selectedTarget % 2 == 0)
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range - selectedTarget / 2, iCol - _attributes.range].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range - selectedTarget / 2, iCol - _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range + (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol - _attributes.range + (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range].isTaken)
            {
                endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range].position;
                GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (selectedTarget % 2 == 0)
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range - selectedTarget / 2, iCol + _attributes.range].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range - selectedTarget / 2, iCol + _attributes.range].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    endPos = GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range - (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].position;
                    GridManager.instance.nodes[iRow + _attributes.range, iCol + _attributes.range - (selectedTarget + 1) / 2].isTaken = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question seem rather unclear to me. Do you have one large grid with nodes you want to traverse, or multiple grids? And if you want to find the next candidates for a given node you should only need to check the neighbor nodes. I'm not sure what the example is supposed to show, but it does not look like typical A* code.

Comment: The space is 40 rows by 40 columns, where each [row, col] is a node on the grid.  I can provide the code for the pathfinding if it is needed, but the problem here is finding the last point of the path. Could you elaborate on the idea of neighbour nodes and how I should go about it?

Comment: Typically you would represent a node by a point (of ints), i.e. [x,y]. So if you start at [2, 3] you generate a list like [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 3], [2, 2], check if these are closed, traverable, compute traversal cost, add to open set etc. Checking if you are at your target should just be `if(currentNode == targetNode)`

Comment: If(currentNode == targetNode) wouldn't work in this case, since a lot of objects are spawned at the same time and they have to accurately draw their path with the spread in mind. If I check constantly if the current node is the target node, the objects will have to react dynamically to the path, instead of drawing it initially once and following it.

Comment: Simple pathfinding finds a path from one node to another in a graph ( and a grid is a kind of graph). What you do with that path is a separate issue. Dealing with temporary blocked nodes needs separate handling that might range from simply redo the path-finding ever n seconds to including a time component in your pathfinding. But it is not clear (to me) what the *actual* issue is. So try to start from the beginning and explain, 1. What is it you are attempting to do. 2. What result you expect. 3. What result you are getting.

Comment: Image for Reference: https://imgur.com/ztJFvYl 
1 & 2. I am attempting to spread the units equally to all teal colored grids in the image, starting from 1 through 9, in that order, and once 9 is taken it goes back to 1 and repeats.
3. Currently, once 9 is reached, a solid frame drop occurs followed by a crash.

Comment: Moving units to some kind of formation is probably a separate problem from the actual path finding. Simplest option would probably be to just assign the targets as `unitIndex % noTargetSquares`.

Comment: Hi Dean Staikov, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally fixed the problem myself by resetting the selectedtarget value to 0 when selectedTarget == aitargets.Length and running the function for finding the path again.